# Decorator / wrapper around python class attribute

Tags: python, python-2.7, properties, wrapper

I am trying to enhance the default `@property` behavior in Python:

```
from functools import wraps

def MyProperty(func):
    def getter(self):
        """Enhance the property"""
        return func(self) + 1

    return property(getter)

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self._foo = foo

    @MyProperty
    def foo(self):
        return self._foo
```

This all works very fine, I get the desired effect

```
A = MyClass(5)
A.foo
>>> 6
```

Since I have learned it that way, I want to apply the `wraps` decorator to the wrapper for good-practice reasons. But if I do write the wrapper as

```
def MyProperty(func):
    @wraps
    def getter(self):
        """Enhance the property"""
        return func(self) + 1

    return property(getter)
```

I now get

```
A = MyClass(5)
A.foo
>>> <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f209f4aa0d0>
```

Which is not what I expect. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
def MyProperty(func):

    @wraps(func)
    def getter(self):
        """Enhance the property"""
        return func(self) + 1

    return property(getter)
```

Comment: It works; could you explain why (or how to find this information)?